# Occurrence of numbers/words in different rows

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file with the following structure:
student_name subject1 grade1 subject2 grade2 ...

I figured out how to count for each subject how many stundents attended, but I don't know how to count for each subject how many of them got grades bigger than 5.

Also I need help in finding for each subject the occurance of the grades and which grade had the most occurance.

If someone could help me out, I would appreciate it!

> ```
> File Content:
> Robert Java 8 Algorithms 8 Math 6
> Andrew Java 9 Algorithms 7 Math 6
> Ben Java 5 Algorithms 10 Math 8
> Jerry Java 7 Algorithms 5 Math 7
> Terry Java 4 Algorithms 5 Math 9
> Ross Java 5 Algorithms 9 Math 7
>
>
> Desired output:
> The subject Java was attended by 6 stundets. Number of students with grade bigger than or equal to 5: 5
> The subject Algorithms was attended by 6 students. Number of students with grade bigger than or equal to 5: 6
> The subject Math was attended by 6 students. Number of students with grade bigger than or equal to 5: 6
>
> Occurance of grades:
> 5:
> 6:
> 7:
> 8:
> 9:
>
> Occurance of grades for Math:
> 6:
> 7:
> 8:
> 9:
> ```

What I got so far:

```
awk ' { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) C[$i]++;} {for (j = 3; j <= NF; j += 2) B[$j]++;} END { for (var in C) print "The ",var," subject was attanded by " C[var], "students" ; for (var3 in B) print "The occurance of grade: ",var3," is : ", B[var3]; }'\n $1
```

Comment: What did you do for the moment ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: awk '
{
for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2)
C[$i]++;}
{for (j = 3; j <= NF; j += 2)
B[$j]++;}

END {
for (var in C)
print "The ",var," subject was attanded by " C[var], "students" ;

for (var3 in B)
print "The occurance of grade: ",var3," is : ", B[var3];
}'\n $1    That's what I got so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a template you can use to add the print formatting...

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2) 
          {k=$i; g=$(i+1); a[k]++; 
           c[k]+=(g>=5); 
           grades[k]=(k in grades?grades[k]:k) ORS g}} 

    END{for(k in a) print k, a[k], c[k]; 
        for(k in grades) print grades[k]}' file

Algorithms 6 6
Math 6 6
Java 6 5
Algorithms
8
7
10
5
5
9
Math
6
6
8
7
9
7
Java
8
9
5
7
4
5
```

`a` array has the counts for subjects and `c` for the ones matching the `>=5` criteria; `grades` has the grades for all subjects.  At the `END` block you iterate through the array/map to pick the stored values.  Note that your "Java" counts are not right in the posted example.